# Elisp: call start-process with a path that includes a space

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a mode that calls an inferior process. The line that starts the process is:

```lisp
(setq grass-process (start-process "grass" "*grass*" "grass" "-text"
                           (concat  (file-name-as-directory 
                                    (cdr grass-location)) 
                           grass-mapset)))
```

`grass-location` and `grass-mapset` are both strings containing the path to the toplevel directory, and to one of the nested directories, respectively, that need to be concatenated as an argument to `set-process`.

This works fine when `grass-location` and `grass-mapset` contain normal directories with no spaces. However, when there's a space in the directory name, it gets dropped when passed to `start-process`, producing the following error:

```
grass-location
=> ("geobase Canada" . "/home/tws/grassdata/geobase Canada")
grass-mapset
=> "PERMANENT"

;; Calling start-process as above, the following error is produced
;; in the *grass* buffer:


Cleaning up temporary files ...
Starting GRASS ...
/home/tws/grassdata/geobaseCanada/PERMANENT: Not a valid GRASS location

Process grass exited abnormally with code 1
```

Note that `geobase Canada` is reduced to `geobaseCanada`. I've tried adding quotes in the `concat` expression to protect that string, but it produces even stranger errors, with the home directory being prepended to the argument.

How do I pass a path name with spaces in it to start-process?

Comment: are you sure the error comes from your `start-process` expression and not from the `grass` program itself? (for example, the second argument seems to be concatenated to the first one; maybe spaces are lost during this process...)

Comment: You're right, I get the same error starting grass from an xterm. Thanks!

Comment: @Francesco can you make this a real answer so this question doesn't get filtered as unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[As suggested by* @event_jr, *I repost my comment here as an answer, since it looks like that was the origin of the problem]*

Your invocation of `start-process` seems to be correct; are you sure the problem doesn't come from the `grass` program itself? (for example, the second argument seems to be concatenated to the first one; maybe spaces are lost during this process...)